# Within group feature selection for PCA

Tags: pca, feature-selection

Let $\mathbf{p} \in R^D$ be the first eigenvector obtained by PCA on a dataset $\mathbf{X} \in R^{N \times D}$.

$$
\mathbf{X}\mathbf{p}
$$

is the first principal component of my dataset. The relative importance of each feature in $\mathbf{X}$ can be interpreted in light of the values in $\mathbf{p}$.

With sparse PCA, I can increase interpretability by reducing the number of features used in that first principal component.

Now, lets say the set of features $\mathcal{D}$ (such that $|\mathcal{D}| = D$) is partionned in groups $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_1 \cup \ldots \cup \mathcal{D}_T $ such that all feature in $\mathcal{D}$ belongs to one and only one group $\mathcal{D}_i$.

My main question is: **Is there an alternative to sparce PCA that would induce sparsity at the group level such that few variable are selected in each group of feature**. I don't want to select a whole group and put the others to zero. Ideally, I would like one feature selected in each group.

Example:

```
input features are: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
groups are: {1, 2} and {3, 4, 5}
the desired algorithm returns a non-zero coefficients in the first eigenvector for features 1 and 4
```

I have considered a couple of ideas already. **Are they bad ideas?**

Considered options:

- Make sparse PCA. Select, in each group, the feature with the highest coefficient. Then, either:

  - Keep only those coefficients. (idea 1)
  - Run PCA again on the selected features. (idea 2)

Note:

- My final goal is PCA so I need **feature selection for PCA** and not the reverse.
- I am working on time series

Comment: I don't think this will work as well in terms of predictive discrimination as keeping the whole group.  But look at some of the data reduction procedures summarized in my [RMS notes](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc) Chapter 4.  What you are describing is similar to _battery reduction_.

Comment: The litterature on battery reduction seems to be scarce and I am not sure it fits to what I am looking for. The definition in your book fits but other ressources that I found were different. From what I understand, battery reduction is about finding the subset of variables in the input variables that best explain the total variance. This is what I understood from "Factor analysis: An applied approach - Cureton & d'Agostino" which you cite. Thank you though :)